# What is the difference between に and で with 震える?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-で

For example:

> 寒さ**に**震える and 寒さ**で**震える

> 恐怖**に**震える and 恐怖**で**震える

It seems like they both mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much difference in these particular cases. Both に and で indicate a cause.

Having said that, I personally sense a subtle difference in nuance. The sentence with に in each pair brings me a more vivid image of the subject enduring the cold or the fear, shivering. This may be because the particle に makes me imagine the subject *in* that situation. It also sounds a bit literary. The sentence with で sounds to me more neutral and matter-of-fact. But this is subjective.