# When do you use に to indicate a cause or reason for something?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, reason

I was reading a children's book and came across the following sentence:

> あまりの寒さに目を覚ました。

I can tell that it means "Because of the extreme cold, he woke up," but I was kind of surprised to see に used as the particle to indicate cause.

An Internet search does tell me that に can be used to indicate a reason or cause, especially, it seems, for feeling verbs, like in the case of something like 雷に驚いた (startled by lightning) or 私に怒っている (angry with me).  But I wouldn't have thought "waking up" was a feeling verb, so I'm not sure why the author used に instead of で to indicate the reason the character woke up.

Is it just a matter of style or personal preference?  Is it idiomatic and I just need to grow more accustomed to when it feels more natural to use に?  Would あまりの寒さで目を覚ました also be correct or does that sound weird?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86575/45489

Answer (score 4):

In short,

- あまりの寒さ**に**目を覚ました is idiomatic.
- あまりの寒さ**で**目を覚ました is equally natural.
- There is a difference in nuance, but it is small enough and you shouldn't worry unless you are translating literary texts.

---

My impression is that the usage of に is common when describing some **reaction**. E.g., あまりのうれしさに泣き出す (From #7 of [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#jn-166083)) is another example of "non-feeling" verb.

---

Some other things vaguely relevant:

- In English, I suppose it is possible to say *I wake up **to** the sound of something* (even if not *to the coldness*).
- The に in に怒る means more object of the anger, not reason. English *angry to* should be unacceptable, but *anger towards someone* should be fine.

So as you mention, it is ultimately a matter of getting accustomed to various usages, but in my opinion に shares much with *to*, even when using *to* itself is not the norm in English expression.

Comment: About the English for に怒る, I think _angry **at**_ works even better.  :)

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - When you say “I woke up to X”, does that mean X caused the subject to wake up, or the subject found himself with X after he woke up?

Comment: @aguijonazo, my sense is that it's closer to the latter -- _"I woke up, and X [was there, was doing something, etc.]"_  Like. _"I woke to the sound of the garbage trucks"_ just means that they woke up, and they heard the garbage trucks.  It doesn't indicate any reason for waking.  To indicate a reason, I might say _"I woke up **because of** X"_, or _"I woke up **due to** X"_, etc.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - Thanks. Then I would say it doesn't quite correspond to に here.

Comment: @aguijonazo: Idiomatically speaking, I’d probably reword things to use the transitive verb _”to wake”_ — something like _”the X woke me”_, as in _”the cold woke me”_ or _”the noise of the neighbor’s dog being sick on my front porch woke me from disturbing dreams of corn chowder...”_ 