# What is the difference between the に used here and で when specifying a reason for a future action?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-で

The following passage comes from a word game that's indirectly describing the story of Little Red Riding Hood (赤ずきん)

> 男に質問を繰り返す女｡
> とある質問**に**男は態度を急変させ､ それ以降､ 質問されることはなくなった｡ 何があった?

I had the part

> とある質問に男は態度を急変させ

explained to me by a Japanese speaker that the に in "とある質問に" is saying this particular question caused the sudden change in attitude

How does this usage of に to specify the cause of a action differ from で being used to specify the cause of an action, like in the following:

> 風邪で今日は休む

In my mind, if the original text was written using で instead of に (とある質問**で**男は...), it still looks correct to me and I don't understand a difference in nuance between the two either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of this type of に is limited to the cause of a psychological reaction.

- [When do you use に to indicate a cause or reason for something?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95996/5010)
- [に in コントロールに苦しまなくなった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72042/5010)
- [How does ''ni'' fit in here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98508/5010)

In your example, とある質問に and とある質問で are completely interchangeable, and I can feel no difference. In simpler and fixed phrases like ～に驚く and ～に怒る, に should be used.

休む is not a psychological reaction, so you cannot say 風邪に会社を休む.

Comment: 彼の怪しい笑顔に不安になった

Here I'm trying to describe how my anxiety rose when I saw this guy's suspicious smile (maybe it looks like he's up to no good). Perhaps it could also be described with で but here my reaction is a non-volitional, psychological response to his face so does に here work?

Comment: @hulapoll1 Yes, and に would be more natural in such a simple case.