# Difference between に受ける and から受ける

Tags: grammar

From Oshi no ko chapter 142,

[image]

She's reading a movie script and commented on how a character Ai appears to share some resemblance to Ruby.

I have doubts about the difference between ルビーから影響を受ける and ルビーに影響を受ける. I suspect they are interchangeable since に can be used to mark source object, similar to に used in passive sentences...?

Comment: In the particular context, there's no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, に and から are interchangeable in this sentence. に can broadly indicate a cause or source (this usage may remind you of [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/101454/5010)). Sometimes the use of に can lead to an ambiguous sentence ([example](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/76413/5010)), but this is not an issue in the sentence in question.