# Usage of に を (not を　に)

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

俺に信頼しきった眼差しに子供時代を思い出す

What exact function do に　を serve here together?

"His gaze full of trust toward me reminds me of my childhood"?

Comment: 「俺に信頼しきった眼差し」<-- I would say 俺**を**信頼しきった眼差し... (Which is correct, ～を信頼する or ～に信頼する ?)

Answer (score 1):

That を is a normal usage as the object marker. 子供時代 is the direct object of the verb 思い出す. The speaker remembers his childhood.

The に after 眼差し is somewhat literary. It is used for something that triggers a certain emotion in the agent (or *doer*) of the verb. It’s related to [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95996/43676). In this particular case, the gaze reminds the speaker of his childhood.

The に after 俺 seems wrong to me. It should be を.