# Use of the を and に particles together with nouns

Tags: particles, particle-に

I'm not talking about を　に　する but rather 　に　をする

So

NounAにNounBをする

Examples:
恐怖に体を固くする

How one should take that sentence? I've seen some TL mark is "By" but I don't understand why?

Comment: The に is this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72043/9831 See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/96009/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86575/9831

Comment: Does this answer your question? [に in コントロールに苦しまなくなった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72042/%e3%81%ab-in-%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%ab%e8%8b%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f)